# Are these roots of unity?

Tags: nt.number-theory

Suppose you are given complex numbers $a_1,\dots,a_N$ which are algebraic over $\mathbb Q$ and satisfy
$1=|a_1|=\dots=|a_k|>|a_{k+1}|\ge\dots\ge|a_N|$.
Assume that
$$
\sum_{j=1}^Na_j^m
$$
is a non-negative integer for every $m\ge 1$. Does it follow that $a_1,\dots,a_k$ are roots of unity?

Comment: Take $a_1 = 1, a_2 = \frac{1}{2}$. For the same question with all of the absolute values equal to $1$, take $a_1 = 1, a_2 = 1, a_3 = \frac{3 + 4i}{5}, a_4 = \frac{3 - 4i}{5}$. Did you mean to ask something different?

Comment: That sum is a complex number, right? So I don't see how you can ask for it to be larger than 0.

Comment: One can ask for it to be real first (which is true in the examples I gave).

Comment: It does follow, though, that $1 \in \{a_1,\ldots,a_k\}$. To amend the problem, I think it could be shown that $\{a_1,\ldots,a_k\} = \mu_k$ unless $1$ appears in $\{a_1,\ldots,a_k\}$ with multiplicity higher than one. This accounts for Qiaochu's example.

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot that the sum should be integral, I corrected this.

Comment: The answer to the revised question is affirmative, and furthermore you do not need the non-negativity condition (integrality suffices); and you have necessarily $N = k$. First show that the integrality of the power sums implies that $\{a_1,\ldots,a_k\}$ partitions (disjointly) into full sets of conjugate algebraic integers (orbits of an algebraic integer under the Galois group). Then the conclusion is immediate from Kronecker's theorem: a non-torsion algebraic integer has at least one conjugate outside the closed unit disc.

Comment: I thought your originally formulated question, which inquired that the power sums be non-negative reals instead of integers, was somewhat more interesting. Only, in order to avoid Qiaochu's counterexample, you would have to impose the added condition that $1$ does not appear more than once among the $a_i$.

Comment: Also, here is a more direct way to phrase the solution to your revised question. The sequence of power sums is bounded and integer-valued, hence eventually periodic (since it satisfies a linear recurrence). Thus there is an infinite arithmetic progression of exponents $m$ on which this sequence takes a constant value. Then the required conclusion, that the $a_i$ are roots of unity, is immediate from the vanishing of an appropriate Vandermonde determinant.

Comment: What linear recurrence does it satisfy?